# Como guardar un dato del localStorage en mi proyecto web sin perder el dato?

Tags: javascript, html, array

primero de todo decir que no tengo bbdd para relizar lo que necesito. Lo que quiero es guardar el nombre que recoge un documento input file para poder mostrarlo y guardarlo en la pantalla de usuarios.

Por el momento estoy utilizando localStorage, el cual registra el dato y me lo devuelve en la tabla de usuarios. Además he convertido el dato en un array , para que me lo muestre como array y no como un dato del localStorage ... sin embargo no consigo hacer que este dato permanezca guardado en la pagina del usuario y que cada vez que el usuario carge un nuevo archivo se cree una lista. Si no que cambia el nombre del documento anterior por el actual.

Alguna idea de cómo puedo hacer esto? Tampoco tengo muy claro si se puede hacer sin base de datos. 
Gracias.

Comment: *LocalStorage* no expira y permite guardar muchos datos. Si los datos no se borran, por parte del usuario o de una aplicación, permanecerán en el navegador. Si tus datos se borran seguramente lo esta haciendo tu código.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Si quieres que el dato persista debes usar una BD, LocalStorage por lo general puede almacenar dependiendo del navegador hasta 5mb de información (otro factor a tener en cuenta). Si puedes adicionar código sería mucho más fácil para la comunidad poder ayudarte

Comment: Por lo que entendido estás intentando almacenar datos de forma centralizada en un el *localStorage*. El *localStorage* es **local**, sólo se almacena en el mismo *browser* del client. Por último, este *localStorage* se puede eliminar (como caché) por lo que los ´datos ahí persistidos siempre deben ser de menor importancia como configuración, cookies, ...

Answer (score 0):

Pongamos un caso hipotético en el que yo tengo la variable **alumno** la cual tienen como valor **Alejandro** y quiero guardarlo en el **localStorage**.

La instrucción que debes utilizar es la siguiente:

```
localStorage.setItem('alumno', 'Alejandro');
```

*Donde el **primer parámetro** equivale a la **llave o nombre** de nuestro elemento a almacenar. Y el **segundo** pertenece a el *valor* de ese elemento.*

Si has guardado tu dato de esa forma, debe **persistir en tu navegador** sin importar que recargues la página siempre y cuando **no borres cache**, ya que esta variable se guarda en la **memoria de nuestro navegador**, por lo tanto los datos están ligados a ese explorador y **existirán hasta que borremos los datos de navegación**. Si tu dato no esta cuando recargas debe ser problema de tu código.

prueba a consultarlo con:

```
var cat = localStorage.getItem('alumno');
```

*Donde el parámetro que te solicita es la llave o nombre de tu elemento.*

Revisa si no lo has borrado en alguna parte de tu código con alguna de estas instrucciones:

```
localStorage.removeItem('alumno');
localStorage.clear();
```

De igual forma si pudieras proporcionar tu código para revisarlo y encontrar el problema, así como la información de tu versión de JS o los frameworks que estés utilizando

Mas informacion sobre localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Sobre todo gracias. Lo que trato de hacer es recoger el nombre de un archivo file, y mostrar el nombre de este archivo en el panel del usuario, tantas veces que el usuario introduzca un archivo file. El problema es que la funcionalidad que realiza el input file la realiza mediante una API (converAPI), por lo que los archivos que el usuario introduce en el input file nunca los registra nuestra bbdd.... Por lo que no conozco la forma de hacer que el nombre de ese archivo file se guarde y lo muestre en forma de listado en el panel usuario. Por ahora mi script es este :

Comment: No me permite introducir código ... estoy utilizando localStorage ya que al menos me deja ver la información introducida en ese momento aunque no se guarde, al introducir la siguiente.

Answer (score 0):

Para mantener el array sin que te lo convierta en un string la mejor opción es convertirlo a un json te dejo un ejemplo

```
function sesioner(){
var matriz = ['ccc','bbb','aaaa']
console.log(matriz)
/*  puedes hacerlo en dos pasos o en uno
    var jsonMatriz = JSON.stringify(matriz);
    localStorage.setItem('files',jsonMatriz);
    yo lo pongo en una linea
*/
localStorage.setItem('pp',JSON.stringify(matriz))
/*  Lo puedes recuperar en dos lineas
  var recuperadoMatriz =localStorage.getItem('pp');
  var arrayRecuperado = JSON.parse(recuperadoMatriz);
    yo lo hago en una linea
*/
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pp')))
}
sesioner();
```

Otra opción es pasarle un string separados por un carácter especial como ; (estilo csv) y luego hacer un split

```
var test='c:\\misDocumentos';
function sessionesString(masDoc){
test+=';'+masDoc;
localStorage.setItem('sesionita', test);
return localStorage.getItem('sesionita').split(';')
}
console.log(sessionesString('c:\\descargas'))
```